Why do different definitions of Thompsons group V describe the same group?
I am interested in Thompson's group $V$. There are multiple different definitions for this group which apparently describe the same group, but my question is why do they describe the same group. The definitions I have encountered most often so far are

Thompson's group $V$ is the group of right-continuous bijections of $S^1$ that map images of dyadic rationals to images of dyadic rationals, that are differentiable except at finitely many images of dyadic rationals such that on each maximal interval on which the function is differentiable, it is linear and the differential is a power of two.

Thompson's group $V$ is the automorphism group of the Cantor algebra $V_{2,1}$


Thanks

$V$ is not the homeomorphism group of the Cantor set. The homeomorphism group of the Cantor set is uncountable, since it contains uncountable subgroups like $C_2^{\infty}$ and $S_{\infty}$.

@QiaochuYuan  The group of order-preserving homeomorphisms of the Cantor set looks (to me) more $V$-like. Might that be the right definition?

Please, add references to definition 2, since something is seriously off there.

You are right, I'm sorry. In "The infinite simple group V of Richard J. Thompson:
presentations by permutations" Thompsons group is defined as "a group of CERTAIN homeomorphisms of the Cantor set" (they go on to explain the details). Since I am mostly interested in the other two cases I removed this part of my question. Thanks.
